# pass more than enough arguments to lib/pq

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

To simplify the code, and prevent from passing similar arguments again and again, I created a method `Put` for some structures as below.
For example, the reason why `UID` is not used here is because `UID` was set as an auto increase value.

```golang
type User struct {
    UID      int
    Name     string
    Username string
    Password string
}

func (user *User) Put(db *sql.DB, query string) (sql.Result, error) {
    return db.Exec(query, u.UID, u.Name, u.Username, u.Password)
}

func main() {
    db := ...
    u := &User{...}

    u.Put(db, `INSERT INTO user(name, username, password) VALUES ($2, $3, $4);`)
}
```

But I get the error below

```
pq: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

(SQL driver is https://github.com/lib/pq)

Comment: Why  does the query parameters start  at `$2`?

Comment: cause method `Put` puts `UID` which is not used in this query, but may be used in other queries.

Comment: Don't separate the query string from its arguments; they belong together and should be treated as a unit. This will keep causing problems like this. In this particular case, why can't you move the query string directly into the Put method? Why does the caller have to supply it? What "other queries" would you ever call this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query `$2, $3...$N`  is the index of the argument that is passed in as extra arguments to `db.Exec()` and they must start from `$1`(if you use `database/sql` package).

I think in your case you may to change `Put` method signature (add `struct values extractor`)

```
func (user *User) Put(db *sql.DB, query string, extractor func(user User)[]interface{}) (sql.Result, error) {
    return db.Exec(query, extractor(*user)...)
}
```

and use one like

```
u.Put(db,`INSERT INTO user(name, username, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);`, func(u User) []interface{} {
    return []interface{}{u.Name, u.Username, u.Password}
})
```